# percent graphical representation as circle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

im planning to do a percentage visualisation using a circle, and am currently trying to figure out what framework / technique to use.

i have used `corePlot` for graphs so far and have been wondering if it might be an option

my ideas are so far:

```
1: use a Core Plot piechart and add a covering circle layer in the middle
2: try to use quartz 2d to do it somehow
```

attached is a mockup how it should look like so you get an idea:

[image]

what do you think might be the best approach here? id like avoid using cover-up subviews and such..

is there any simple solution i might be missing?

thanks in advance
sebastian

(PS: i do not hope for any code here, just a general `fingerpoint` to the right direction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As more of an alternative than an actual straightforward CorePlot answer, you could display your percentage in a customized version of the [UICircularProgressView](https://github.com/Zedenem/UICircularProgressView) control which I can personally vouch for.

Comment: wow! this is spectacular. exactly one hundred percent what i was looking for! have big thanks!